# About the context menu setting when the link file is selected

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu, lnk

I tried to set to execute the specified command for the target file / folder
by passing the path to the file / folder with a placeholder in the context menu.

When I selected the shortcut (link file) and executed it ,
the passed path  is not "the path of the link file itself" but "the folder path of the link destination".
I tried using "% 1" and "% L" as placeholders.

Since passing "folder path of link destination" is not good, I want to:
(A) set the path to be passed in the placeholder to "the path of the link file itself"
* Excluding from process / Processing as the link file at the receiving destination

(B) display the context menu for the shortcut (link file) ONLY
(i.e. displayed differently from the general folder) when selected

about (b),
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ lnkfile \ shell 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ AllFilesystemObjects \ shell 
I tried to change the contents with the same key and give priority to the setting of lnkfile,
but the setting of the latter (AllFilesytem ..) got priority.

When you make it, it will be displayed differently from the general folder
I would like to take one of the measures, but is there a good idea?

We would appreciate it if you could ask us if there are any parts that are lacking in confirmation or explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you have done or what you are trying to do. (For example "passing the path to the file/folder with a placeholder in the context menu" - How did you pass the path to the context menu? Context menus are just HMENUs; they don't have paths.) Can you post the code you're using to create the shortcut, and describe what you expect to happen and what you actually get?

Comment: I activate the following 2 sets in the registry:
Set1
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\AAAA`  _[property -name (default)  -value bbbb]_
` HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\AAAA\Command`   _[property -name (default)  -value BBBB %1]_

Set2
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shell\AAAA `  _[property -name (default)  -value cccc]_
 `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shell\AAAA\Command`  _[property -name (default) -value CCCC %1]_

**AAAA:Key
BBBB,CCCC:Command
bbbb,cccc:Displayed Name in the context menu**

Comment: Subsequently, when I select files/folders in the Explorer, bbbb is displayed in the context menu.
And after clicking bbbb, BBBB with arguments of the paths of selected files/folders is kicked.
(When selecting lnkfile of the folder, it passes not "the path of the lnkfile itself" but "the folder path of the link destination")

Comment: Finally, I want to solve either Problem 1 or Problem2 as follows:

/Problem 1
This has applied all objects including lnkfiles(shortcuts), i.e. Set2 is lower priority than Set1.
I want to display cccc only when I select lnkfiles(shortcuts).

/Problem 2
When I select lnkfiles(shortcuts),
I want to kick bbbb with arguments of the path about the selected lnkfile itself.